# Only one instance of 'UniqueExpiryCallback' can be registered in the 'MessageGroupStore'

Tags: spring-integration

In

```
    org.springframework.integration.store.AbstractMessageGroupStore {
    ...
    @Override
    public void registerMessageGroupExpiryCallback(MessageGroupCallback callback) {
        if (callback instanceof UniqueExpiryCallback) {
            boolean uniqueExpiryCallbackPresent =
                    this.expiryCallbacks.stream()
                            .anyMatch(UniqueExpiryCallback.class::isInstance);

            if (!uniqueExpiryCallbackPresent && this.logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
                this.logger.error("Only one instance of 'UniqueExpiryCallback' can be registered in the " +
                        "'MessageGroupStore'. Use a separate 'MessageGroupStore' for each aggregator/resequencer.");
            }
        }

        this.expiryCallbacks.add(callback);
    }
   ...
}
```

shouldn't be any '!' sign in if clause by check of uniqueExpiryCallbackPresent variable, because in this constellation I get ERROR log any time I use .aggregator() in the configuration of the flow.
It is 5.1.1 version of spring-integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks; this was already reported and is fixed [on master](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/9832f61d2a0a8111f1773fdc29af40c15f580e70) and will be in 5.1.2.